# Keep manual changes of EF auto-generated classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

As you know, when we generate a model using the entity framework those files are automatically generated and manual changes will be overwritten if we change the model.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is, how can we keep those manual changes in place?

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a date")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
```

It's pretty hard to maintain any manual changes, like the one above, made to those classes.

What kind of strategy would you use to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 4):

Create a new file and add a partial class with same name as your generated entity.

You can see an example [here](https://robbincremers.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/entity-framework-using-partial-classes-to-add-business-logic-and-validation-to-generated-entities/). More about partial classes you can read on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Let's say EF generated next class

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MetadataType(typeof(EmployeeMeta))]
public partial class Employee
{ 

}
```

than in your project create a new file with same signature and same namespace

```
public partial class Employee
{
     //custom logic here
}
```